# ZuulException: Forwarding error, Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

Am facing the below `ZuulException` exception due to Broken pipe issue in my Integeration testing environment. Have just a single service deployed but still am getting the below exception and ideally it should be available all the time.
This issue is intermittent, sometime it is working and sometime it isn't. Have anyone faced this issue and is there any addition configurations to be done?

**LOG TRACE**

```
com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
                at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:145) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.0.0.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:110) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.0.0.RELEASE]
                at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:112) ~[zuul-core-1.0.28.jar!/:na]
                at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:197) ~[zuul-core-1.0.28.jar!/:na]
                at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:161) ~[zuul-core-1.0.28.jar!/:na]
                at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:120) ~[zuul-core-1.0.28.jar!/:na]
                at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:84) ~[zuul-core-1.0.28.jar!/:na]

Caused by: com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: userManagementRibbonCommand failed and no fallback available.
                at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$20.call(AbstractCommand.java:816) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.0-RC6.jar!/:na]
                at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$20.call(AbstractCommand.java:798) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.0-RC6.jar!/:na]
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$1.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:77) ~[rxjava-1.0.4.jar!/:1.0.4]
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:70) ~[rxjava-1.0.4.jar!/:1.0.4]
Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: null
                at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:123) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.0-RC13.jar!/:na]
                at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:81) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.0-RC13.jar!/:na]

Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
                at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
                at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
                at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
                at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:159) ~[httpcore-4.3.3.jar!/:4.3.3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will fix your problem but if you already don't have it then add this to your application.yml file

```
   hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 60000

    ribbon: 
     ConnectTimeout: 3000
     ReadTimeout: 60000
```